# File.ReadAllText() of file deployment by DeploymentItem attribute on AppVeyor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest, appveyor, vstest

I have a problem with loading text from file, which appears only on AppVeyor. I'm reading text from file, like:

`string input = File.ReadAllText(Path);`

Next I want to split this string to array - I want to have each line, I'am doing it like this:

`string [] array = input.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine });`

And on my PC it works. I have some unit test (MSTest) with `DeploymentItem` attribute and I have lines in that array.

But on AppVeyor, where I want to have CI, that array has only one string.

I've tested it also with VSTestConsole on my PC and it works, so it isn't problem with eg. parameters of `VSTest.Console.exe`

Is it problem with `Environment.NewLine` string? I know I could do it by the other way, but:

1. I want to use `String.Split()` method because I need `StringSplitOptions` enum to make my code more readable instead of eg. `foreach` loop or something else.
2. I want to know why it isn't working :)

Comment: My guess is sources are cloned with `\n` as a new line while you are trying to split the string with `\r\n`.

Comment: What is the value of `Environment.NewLine` in the `AppVeyor` environment?

Comment: Have you tried: `string[] array = input.Split(new[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`?

Comment: According to the comments in [This Discussion](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/642), it may have to do with the way `git` handles `CRLF` - it replaces `CR LF` with just `LF`

Comment: Thanks a lot @RufusL! Way with changing the way how git handles CRLFs is good, I'll also try use code you pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try reading the file using

```
string[] array = File.ReadLines(Path);
```

Does that still give you an array with only one item?